# How to determine basis by Reducing a sets

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to do Reducing set of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$

So that form basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

for vectors:

$\displaystyle x_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}x_2=\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}x_3=\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 2\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
x_4=\begin{bmatrix} -2\\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing that

$$\det(\mathbf{x}_1\,\mathbf{x}_2\,\mathbf{x}_3)=-16\neq0,$$
$$\det(\mathbf{x}_1\,\mathbf{x}_2\,\mathbf{x}_4)=4\neq0,$$
$$\det(\mathbf{x}_1\,\mathbf{x}_3\,\mathbf{x}_4)=8\neq0,$$
$$\det(\mathbf{x}_2\,\mathbf{x}_3\,\mathbf{x}_4)=-4\neq0,$$

we see that any set of three vectors will form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.